# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined when using fetch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As in the title, I'm confused about the behavior of fetch calling the setState method in a React component.

This way it works:

```
    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then((json) => {
            this.setState({page: json});
        });
```

This way it fails:

```
    fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        }).then(function (json) {
            console.log('parsed json', json);

            this.setState({page: json}); // Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

        }).catch(function (ex) {
            console.log('parsing failed', ex)
        });
```

What's the reason of such behavior?

Comment: you can not refer to the instance using this in the function block when defined like that. this does not the component you want to because the scope changes in function definition.

Comment: This has nothing to do with React. Read up on the difference between arrow functions and "normal" functions.

Comment: Normally, 'this' changes inside of a function, depending on how its called. However, "fat arrow functions" (=>) have what's called "lexical this" which basically means that it can't change.

Comment: All clear now, thanks!